# Calling web service from windows service (load balanced servers)

Tags: .net, web-services, windows-services

We have a web service running on a server and it is invoked by a windows service running on 2 servers, in total there are 3 servers.

Sporadically, (say once in a month / 3 months / 6 months) the windows service is logging this error message "There were not enough free threds in the threadpool to complete the opration".

The webservice is simple, it takes a parameter and returns a string.

After the error occurs that particular windows service on the server fails for subsequent requests.

Not sure of this cause of this error, any help follks?

Comment: In the Windows Service, are you using "Add Service Reference", or "Add Web Reference"? Also, are you properly using `using` blocks?

Answer (score 0):

This problem used to occur frequently in ASP.NET 1.x applications which made lots of concurrent outbound web service requests, for the reasons explained in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;821268).

The HTTP stack in .NET 2.0 was rewritten to make it much less likely to happen, but as I understand it the problem can still arise if the concurrent load pattern leads to sufficiently heavy thread pool usage.

You can probably reduce or even eliminate its incidence by careful tuning of the thread pool parameters for the Windows service application.

Comment: The outbound call is made from windows service and How do I tune thread pool parameter in windows application?